# adding items to MutableList using viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, mutablelist

I have a mutable list created in a viewmodel file that saves the data

```
  //questions they cheated on
    var cheatedList = mutableListOf<Int>(6)
```

I linked the viewmodel file with the file that has functions this way

```
  private val quizViewModel : QuizViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(QuizViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

it is working fine and i checked it. all i need from it is to save a content of Integers into a mutable list... I use this function to do so

```
showAnswerButton.setOnClickListener {
        val answerText = when{
            answerIsTrue -> R.string.true_button
            else -> R.string.false_button
        }
        answerTextView.setText(answerText)
        //create a function to return the result to MainActivity
        setAnswerShownResult(true)
        cheaterStatus = true
        quizViewModel.cheatedList.add(currentIndex)
        println(quizViewModel.cheatedList)
    }
```

the good news is, it saves the index into the list... the bad news is once i move back to another activity, the list is destroyed and nothing is saved in it anymore...
how can i keep the mutablelist saved even if i closed the activity?

Comment: [Take your pick.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) Or, if you don’t need to remember the values between application sessions, you could use Fragments instead of Activities; i.e. use a single Activity to host all the Fragments and scope the ViewModel to the Activity instead of the Fragments. This is recommended by the Android team anyway (single Activity architecture).

Comment: it seems that every time the activities is destroyed, it erases all the data in the view model... right?

Comment: No, the data is preserved if the Activity is temporarily destroyed and recreated for a configuration change. But if the Activity is finished, then it’s ViewModel is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be saved even after closing the application and re opening it (Not temporary closing) you can use local storage like Room to save the data...
But if you only want to save the data in a session then as Tenfour04 said you can use a activity and multiple fragment and use a single viewmodel pattern to save.....